# @GenericGenerator in package-info.java not working JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.1, package-info

I'm trying to add a `Generator` on `package-info.java` so that I don't have to re-write same code on top of every `@Entity` class. But when I try to run the program **Application** I get an error.

```
Session Factory could not be created.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Unknown Id.generator: ID_GENERATOR
```

If I apply `@GenericGenerator` on top on `@Entity` class it works just fine. Am I missing some key point here.

I found this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742667/using-genericgenerator-in-a-package-level-annotation) but the answer posted there didn't work for me.

---

#### Configurations

`package-info.java`

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
    name = "ID_GENERATOR",
    strategy = "enhanced-sequence",
    parameters = {
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "sequence_name",
            value = "JPA_SEQUENCE"
        ),
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "initial_value",
            value = "1"
        )
    }
)
package com.example.hibernate.model;
```

`Student.java`

```
package com.example.hibernate.model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
}
```

`persistence.xml`

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


        <class>com.example.hibernate.model.Student</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="sa" />
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should simply add the package that consists in itself GenericGenerator in your persistence.xml.

The example

```
<class>com.example.hibernate.model</class>
<class>com.example.hibernate.model.Student</class>
```

Comment: After adding package in peristence.xml file, I am getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hibernate.model. Can you please suggest, If i am missing something

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution that I found is to use `@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator` on every `@Entity` class like

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_S", sequenceName = "ID_GENERATOR")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MY_S")
    private int id;

}
```

That's little bit of less **copy and pasting** to do than, to define `GenericGenerator` on every `@Entity` class.

---

We can also eliminate use of `@SequenceGenerator` in each `@Entity` class but we need to work with `XML` in this case.

Create a `orm.xml` and add this file as `mapping-file` on `persistence.xml`

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

Inside of `orm.xml` we define the `sequence-generator`

```
<sequence-generator name="MY_S"
                    sequence-name="ID_GENERATOR"/>
```