# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: ID_GENERATOR

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I'm trying to create a @GenericGenerator annotation at the package level so it can be used by all the entities in the package.

1) I have a package-info.java class with the annotation:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR",                  strategy = "enhanced-sequence", parameters = {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "JPWH_SEQUENCE"),
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000") })
package com;
```

2) In that same package, I have an entity with the following attribute:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
private Long id;
```

this is resulting in an exception "Unknown Id.generator: ID_GENERATOR". If I include the @GenericGenerator annotation in the entity class, it works fine. However, I want to move this to the package level so I can reuse it in other entities.

Any ideas where the disconnect could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you can change the entity code to this:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_id_generator", sequenceName="ID_GENERATOR")
@GeneratedValue(generator="my_id_generator")
private Long id;
```

source: [link](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/org-hibernate-annotationexception-unknown-id-generator/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you make a design mistake. 
If you want a common thing between your model classes, use inheritance. 
You can create a AbstractEntity class which defines the id generator. And every classes of your model inherite from this abtract. 
It is a common pattern. You can also put the traditional common attributes created, createdBy, updated, updatedBy and why not an sysname. 
Using an hibernate id generator does not really have sense.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I put the package-info file in a package and then populated it with sub-packages as so:

```
org.persistence
    package-info
org.persistence.someclasses
    PersistenceClass
org.persistennce.otherclasess
    OtherPersistenceClass
```

This worked with no other action for some hours. Then I added, changed and deleted some values in the `cfg.file` and this worked no more, until I added the line `<mapping package="org.persistence"/>`

Then it worked again. I found that answer here:

[Using @GenericGenerator in a package level annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742667/using-genericgenerator-in-a-package-level-annotation)